# Finding the subinterval for which $f_{n}(x) = \frac{n\sin(x)}{1+n^2\sin^2(x)}$ is Uniformly Convergent in

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Let $f_{n}(x) = \frac{n\sin(x)}{1+n^2\sin^2(x)}$ for $x \in [0,\pi]$. For $\delta > 0$, I want to find $E_{\delta} \subset [0, \pi]$ where $f_{n}(x)$ converges uniformly and $\mu([0,\pi] \setminus E_{\delta}) < \delta$ where $\mu$ denotes measure.

I've shown that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{x \in [0,\pi]} \left \{ \frac{n\sin(x)}{1+n^2\sin^2(x)} \right \} \neq 0$, but am not sure how to find this $E_{\delta}$. Ideas?

Comment: If $E_\delta$ is an interval in $[0,\pi]$ and $\mu([0,\pi]\setminus E_\delta) = 0$, then wouldn't $E_\delta$ have to contain all of $[0,\pi]$ except possibly the endpoints?

Comment: @AlexisOlson I do not know the answer to your question

Comment: @AlexisOlson   Why should $E_{\delta}$ be an interval? By the way, a set with measure zero may contain a lot of points. For example the well known Cantor set $K$ has measure zero but the cardinality of the continuum.

Comment: @SpettroDiA Note that I specified $E_\delta$ is an interval since OP asked about a subinterval in the title. In any case, it seems odd to me that removing a $\delta$-small set from an interval is supposed to result in a null set.

Comment: I am sorry, that is the title, you're right.

Comment: $E_{\delta}$ is indeed a subinterval of $[0, \pi]$

Comment: Did you mean to write $\mu([0,\pi]\setminus E_\delta) < \delta$?

Comment: @AlexisOlson oh wow. Yes.

Comment: Ah, OK. Then $E_\delta = (\delta/3, \pi - \delta/3)$ will work, but the hard part is proving it.

Comment: Yes, that is more the reason why I posted here haha. How about explainig why that works to start

Comment: Hint:

The supremum

$$\sup_{x \in [0,\pi]} \left \{ \frac{n\sin(x)}{1+n^2\sin^2(x)} \right \} = 0.5$$

is attained at only two points in $[0,\pi]$ where $x = \arcsin(1/n)$. What happens to these points as $n \to \infty?$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look on the interval $[0,\pi/2]$ and choose an integer $m > 2$.

Then for $n > 2m^2$ and $x > \frac{1}{m}$, we have

\begin{eqnarray}
2m^2 < n &\iff& 2m < \frac{n}{m}\\
 &\implies& 2m < nx \tag{since $x> \tfrac{1}{m}$}\\
 &\implies& \frac{2}{nx} < \frac{1}{m}
\end{eqnarray}

Now because $\sin (x) > \frac{x}{2}$ in $[0,\pi/2]$, we have $\frac{1}{\sin(x)} < \frac{2}{x}$ so that

$$\frac{n \sin(x)}{1+n^2 \sin^2(x)} < \frac{n \sin(x)}{n^2 \sin^2(x)} = \frac{1}{n \sin(x)} < \frac{1}{n \frac{x}{2}} = \frac{2}{nx} < \frac{1}{m}$$

Thus for large enough $n$, $f_n(x) <  \frac{1}{m}$ on the interval $\left(\frac{1}{m},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$.

---

You can apply a symmetry argument to get a similar result on the interval $[\pi/2,\pi]$.

Finally, for $\delta > 0$, pick $m > \frac{1}{3\delta}$ and $E_\delta = \left(\frac{1}{m},\pi-\frac{1}{m}\right)$